# putting words in react native shapes

Tags: react-native, text, components, shapes

i am trying to add words into my square but when i put a long sentence in the box it cuts off a good amount, does anyone know how to make it that it can start a new line instead of continuing out of the box? my code is below for the square and for the text

```
        <View style={square}>
            <Text
              style={{
                alignItems:'flex-start',
                allowFontScaling: 'True',
                alignContent: 'True',
                color: 'white',
                alignItems: 'True',
                fontSize: 10,
              }}>this is where my long sentence goes to test out my words in the box                </Text>
          </View>
const square = { 
  width: 120,
  height: 80,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#6930C3',
  flex:1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the props [numberOfLines](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#numberoflines) and [ellipsizeMode](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#ellipsizemode) to solve your problem.

```js
function Example() {
    return (
        <View style={{
            width: 120,
            height: 80,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#6930C3',
            margin: 20,
            //padding: 20,
            //flex:1
        }}>
            <Text
                style={{
                    alignItems: 'flex-start',
                    //allowFontScaling: 'True',
                    //alignContent: 'True',
                    color: 'white',
                    //alignItems: 'True',
                    fontSize: 10,
                }}
                // numberOfLines={4}
                // ellipsizeMode={'clip'}
                >
                this is where my long sentence goes to test out my words in the box 4
                this is where my long sentence goes to test out my words in the box 3 
                this is where my long sentence goes to test out my words in the box 2
                this is where my long sentence goes to test out my words in the box 1
                  </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried the number of lines prop but it didn’t actually make the sentence the number of lines I wanted. For ellipsizeMode what should the value be?

Comment: Can you an example of what you get ? I put my code in my answer and text do this by default